# How to ensure unique index on null values?

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing

I have a mongo DB.
The structure of the object of my object is for arguments sakes:

```
@Document
public class Order
{
   @Id
   private String id;
   @Indexed
   private String A;
   private String B;
   @Indexed
   private String C;
   @Indexed
   private String D;
   @Indexed(unique = true)
   private String E;
   private String F;
}
```

So occasionally the field E can be null. If it is, I still want to persist the Order into the DB.
Occasionally E is not null, if it is not null I want to ensure exclusivity when I persist the Order.

Is this possible? I've read up on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/ and I've managed to get it indexed on E when it's populated by running the command on Robo3t:
`db.Order.createIndex( { "E": 1 }, { unique: true } )` but when the E is null, the Order does not get persisted onto Mongo.

Furthermore, is it possible to say something along the lines of:

Ensure F and D is unique ONLY when E is null and persist the order?

Comment: It is possible that the unique index allows one `null` value only. An option is to use _partial indexing_.

Comment: @prasad_ do you have an idea on how i'd be able to write such indexing expression?

Comment: You can refer the driver API docs. Optionally, you can create the index in the `mongo` shell or any such tool. Please refer the MongoDB Manual.